# postgrey has problems with freenet

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

my postifix server does not receive mails from freenet

mail.log:

```
Jul 22 21:04:03 host postfix/smtpd[4100]: connect from mout3.freenet.de[2001:748:100:40::2:5]
Jul 22 21:04:03 host postgrey[2749]: action=pass, reason=triplet found, client_name=mout3.freenet.de, client_address=2001:748:100:40::2:5, sender=someone@freenet.de, recipient=someone@myserver.de
Jul 22 21:04:03 host postgrey[2749]: action=pass, reason=triplet found, client_name=mout3.freenet.de, client_address=2001:748:100:40::2:5, sender=someone@freenet.de, recipient=someone@myserver.de
Jul 22 21:04:03 host postfix/smtpd[4100]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mout3.freenet.de[2001:748:100:40::2:5]: 450 4.1.7 <someone@freenet.de>: Sender address rejected: unverified address: host emig.freenet.de[195.4.92.217] said: 457 Greylisted, please come back later. (in reply to RCPT TO command); from=<someone@freenet.de> to=<someone@myserver.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<mout3.freenet.de>
Jul 22 21:04:03 host postfix/smtpd[4100]: disconnect from mout3.freenet.de[2001:748:100:40::2:5]
```

other senders like t-online are working.
I do not know what i can do.

**Update**
Try to use /etc/postgrey/whitelist_clients but same problem:

```
Jul 22 21:43:35 host postfix/smtpd[3930]: connect from mout1.freenet.de[2001:748:100:40::2:3]
Jul 22 21:43:35 host postgrey[2742]: action=pass, reason=client whitelist, client_name=mout1.freenet.de, client_address=2001:748:100:40::2:3, sender=someone@freenet.de, recipient=someone@myserver.de
Jul 22 21:43:35 host postgrey[2742]: action=pass, reason=client whitelist, client_name=mout1.freenet.de, client_address=2001:748:100:40::2:3, sender=someone@freenet.de, recipient=someone@myserver.de
Jul 22 21:43:35 host postfix/smtpd[3930]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mout1.freenet.de[2001:748:100:40::2:3]: 450 4.1.7 <someone@freenet.de>: Sender address rejected: unverified address: host emig.freenet.de[195.4.92.217] said: 457 Greylisted, please come back later. (in reply to RCPT TO command); from=<someone@freenet.de> to=<someone@myserver.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<mout1.freenet.de>
Jul 22 21:43:35 host postfix/smtpd[3930]: disconnect from mout1.freenet.de[2001:748:100:40::2:3]
```

**Update 2** add whitelist

```
# postgrey whitelist for mail client hostnames
# --------------------------------------------
# put this file in /etc/postgrey or specify its path
# with --whitelist-clients=xxx
#
# postgrey version: 1.34, build date: 2011-05-04

# Debian-specific additions
# I *know* they run real mail queues, so greylisting only creates
# bigger load for them.
debconf.org
debian.org
spi-inc.org

# greylisting.org: Southwest Airlines (unique sender, no retry)
southwest.com
# greylisting.org: isp.belgacom.be (wierd retry pattern)
isp.belgacom.be
# greylisting.org: Ameritrade (no retry)
ameritradeinfo.com
# greylisting.org: Amazon.com (unique sender with letters)
amazon.com
# 2004-05-20: Linux kernel mailing-list (unique sender with letters)
vger.kernel.org
# 2004-06-02: karger.ch, no retry
karger.ch
# 2004-06-02: lilys.ch, (slow: 4 hours)
server-x001.hostpoint.ch
# 2004-06-09: roche.com (no retry)
gw.bas.roche.com
# 2004-06-09: newsletter (no retry)
mail.hhlaw.com
# 2004-06-09: no retry (reported by Ralph Hildebrandt)
prd051.appliedbiosystems.com
# 2004-06-17: swissre.com (no retry)
swissre.com
# 2004-06-17: dowjones.com newsletter (unique sender with letters)
returns.dowjones.com
# 2004-06-18: switch.ch (works but personnel is confused by the error)
domin.switch.ch
# 2004-06-23: accor-hotels.com (slow: 6 hours)
accor-hotels.com
# 2004-06-29: rr.com (no retry, reported by Duncan Hill)
/^ms-smtp.*\.rr\.com$/
# 2004-06-29: cox.net (no retry, reported by Duncan Hill)
/^lake.*mta.*\.cox\.net$/
# 2004-06-29: motorola.com (no retry)
mot.com
# 2004-07-01: nic.fr (address verification, reported by Arnaud Launay)
nic.fr
# 2004-07-01: verizon.net (address verification, reported by Bill Moran and Eric, adapted by Adam C. Mathews)
/^s[cv]\d+pub\.verizon\.net$/
# 2004-07-02: cs.columbia.edu (no retry)
cs.columbia.edu
# 2004-07-02: papersinvited.com (no retry)
66.216.126.174
# 2004-07-02: telekom.de (slow: 6 hours)
/^mail\d+\.telekom\.de$/
# 2004-07-04: tiscali.dk (slow: 12 hours, reported by Klaus Alexander Seistrup)
/^smtp\d+\.tiscali\.dk$/
# 2004-07-04: freshmeat.net (address verification)
freshmeat.net
# 2004-07-11: zd-swx.com (unique sender with letters, reported by Bill Landry)
zd-swx.com
# 2004-07-11: lockergnome.wc09.net (unique sender with letters, reported by Bill Landry)
lockergnome.wc09.net
# 2004-07-19: mxlogic.net (no retry, reported by Eric)
p01m168.mxlogic.net
p02m169.mxlogic.net
# 2004-09-08: intel.com (pool on different subnets) 
/^fmr\d+\.intel\.com$/
# 2004-09-17: cox-internet.com (no retry, reported by Rod Roark)
/^fe\d+\.cox-internet\.com$/
# 2004-10-11: logismata.ch (no retry)
logismata.ch
# 2004-11-25: brief.cw.reum.de (no retry, reported by Manuel Oetiker)
brief.cw.reum.de
# 2004-12-03: ingeno.ch (no retry)
qmail.ingeno.ch
# 2004-12-06: rein.ch (no retry)
mail1.thurweb.ch
# 2005-01-26: tu-ilmenau.de (no retry)
piggy.rz.tu-ilmenau.de
# 2005-04-06: polymed.ch (no retry)
mail.polymed.ch
# 2005-06-08: hu-berlin.de (slow: 6 hours, reported by Joachim Schoenberg)
rz.hu-berlin.de
# 2005-06-17: gmail.com (big pool, reported by Beat Mueller)
proxy.gmail.com
# 2005-06-23: cacert.org (address verification, reported by Martin Lohmeier)
cacert.org
# 2005-07-27: polytech.univ-mrs.fr (no retry, reported by Giovanni Mandorino)
polytech.univ-mrs.fr
# 2005-08-05: gnu.org (address verification, reported by Martin Lohmeier)
gnu.org
# 2005-08-17: ciphirelabs.com (needs fast responses, reported by Sven Mueller)
cs.ciphire.net
# 2005-11-11: lufthansa (no retry, reported by Peter Bieringer)
/^gateway\d+\.np4\.de$/
# 2005-11-23: arcor-online.net (slow: 12 hours, reported by Bernd Zeimetz)
/^mail-in-\d+\.arcor-online\.net$/
# 2005-12-29: netsolmail.com (no retry, reported by Gareth Greenaway)
netsolmail.com
# mail.likopris.si (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
193.77.153.67
# jcsw.nato.int (several servers, no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
195.235.39
# tesla.vtszg.hr (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
tesla.vtszg.hr
# mailgw*.iai.co.il (pool of several servers, reported by Vito Robar)
/^mailgw.*\.iai\.co\.il$/
# gw.stud-serv-mb.si (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
gw.stud-serv-mb.si
# mail.commandtech.com (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
216.238.112.99
# duropack.co.at (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
193.81.20.195
# mail.esimit-tech.si (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
193.77.126.208
# mail.resotel.be (ocasionally no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
80.200.249.216
# mail2.alliancefr.be (ocasionally no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
mail2.alliancefr.be
# webserver.turboinstitut.si (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
webserver.turboinstitut.si
# mil.be (pool of different servers, reported by Vito Robar)
193.191.218.141
193.191.218.142
193.191.218.143
194.7.234.141
194.7.234.142
194.7.234.143
# mail*.usafisnews.org (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
/^mail\d+\.usafisnews\.org$/
# odk.fdv.uni-lj.si (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
/^odk.fdv.uni-lj.si$/
# rak-gentoo-1.nameserver.de (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
rak-gentoo-1.nameserver.de
# dars.si (ocasionally no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
mx.dars.si
# cosis.si (no retry, reported by Vito Robar)
213.143.66.210
# mta?.siol.net (sometimes no or slow retry; they use intermail, reported by Vito Robar)
/^mta[12].siol.net$/
# pim-N-N.quickinspirationsmail.com (unique sender, reported by Vito Robar)
/^pim-\d+-\d+\.quickinspirationsmail\.com$/
# flymonarch (no retry, reported by Marko Djukic)
flymonarch.com
# wxs.nl (no retry, reported by Johannes Fehr)
/^p?smtp.*\.wxs\.nl$/
# ibm.com (big pool, reported by Casey Peel)
ibm.com
# messagelabs.com (big pool, reported by John Tobin)
/^mail\d+\.messagelabs\.com$/
# ptb.de (slow, reported by Joachim Schoenberg)
berlin.ptb.de
# registrarmail.net (unique sender names, reported by Simon Waters)
registrarmail.net
# google.com (big pool, reported by Matthias Dyer, Martin Toft)
google.com
# orange.fr (big pool, reported by Lo�c Le Loarer)
/^smtp\d+\.orange\.fr$/
# citigroup.com (slow retry, reported by Michael Monnerie)
/^smtp\d+.citigroup.com$/
# cruisingclub.ch (no retry)
mail.ccs-cruising.ch
# digg.com (no retry, Debian #406774)
diggstage01.digg.com
# liberal.ca (retries only during 270 seconds, Debian #406774)
smtp.liberal.ca
# pi.ws (pool + long retry, Debian #409851)
/^mail[12]\.pi\.ws$/
# rambler.ru (big pool, reported by Michael Monnerie)
rambler.ru
# free.fr (big pool, reported by Denis Sacchet)
/^smtp[0-9]+-g[0-9]+\.free\.fr$/
/^postfix[0-9]+-g[0-9]+\.free\.fr$/
# thehartford.com (pool + long retry, reported by Jacob Leifman)
/^netmail\d+\.thehartford\.com$/
# abb.com (only one retry, reported by Roman Plessl)
/^nse\d+\.abb\.com$/
# 2007-07-27: sourceforge.net (sender verification)
lists.sourceforge.net
# 2007-08-06: polytec.de (no retry, reported by Patrick McLean)
polytec.de
# 2007-09-06: qualiflow.com (no retry, reported by Alex Beckert)
/^mail\d+\.msg\.oleane\.net$/
# 2007-09-07: nrl.navy.mil (no retry, reported by Axel Beckert)
nrl.navy.mil
# 2007-10-18: aliplast.com (long retry, reported by Johannes Feigl)
mail.aliplast.com
# 2007-10-18: inode.at (long retry, reported by Johannes Feigl)
/^mx\d+\..*\.inode\.at$/
# 2008-02-01: bol.com (no retry, reported by Frank Breedijk)
/^.*?.server.arvato-systems.de$/
# 2008-06-05: registeredsite.com (no retry, reported by Fred Kilbourn)
/^(?:mail|fallback-mx)\d+.atl.registeredsite.com$/
# 2008-07-17: mahidol.ac.th (no retry, reported by Alex Beckert)
saturn.mahidol.ac.th
# 2008-07-18: ebay.com (big pool, reported by Peter Samuelson)
ebay.com
# 2008-07-22: yahoo.com (big pool, reported by Juan Alonso)
yahoo.com
# 2008-11-07: facebook (no retry, reported by Tim Freeman)
/^outmail\d+\.sctm\.tfbnw\.net$/
# 2009-02-10: server14.cyon.ch (long retry, reported by Alex Beckert)
server14.cyon.ch
# 2009-08-19: 126.com (big pool)
/^m\d+-\d+\.126\.com$/
# 2010-01-08: tifr.res.in (no retry, reported by Alex Beckert)
home.theory.tifr.res.in
# 2010-01-08: 1blu.de (long retry, reported by Alex Beckert)
ms4-1.1blu.de
# 2010-03-17: chello.at (big pool, reported by Jan-willem van Eys)
/^viefep\d+-int\.chello\.at$/
# 2010-05-31: nic.nu (long retry, reported by Ivan Sie)
mx.nic.nu
# 2010-06-10: Microsoft servers (long/no retry, reported by Roy McMorran)
bigfish.com
frontbridge.com
microsoft.com
# 2010-06-18: Google/Postini (big pool, reported by Warren Trakman)
postini.com
# 2011-02-04: evanzo-server.de (no retry, reported by Andre Hoepner)
/^mx.*\.evanzo-server\.de$/
# 2011-05-02: upcmail.net (big pool, reported by Michael Monnerie)
upcmail.net

gateway.startcom.org
freenet.de
```

first try looks like:

```
Jul 22 19:48:39 host postfix/smtpd[22813]: connect from mout1.freenet.de[2001:748:100:40::2:3]
Jul 22 19:48:39 host postfix/smtp[22839]: 8EFA81EF49: host emig.freenet.de[195.4.92.216] said: 457 Greylisted, please come back later. (in reply to RCPT TO command)
Jul 22 19:48:40 host postfix/smtp[22839]: 8EFA81EF49: to=<someone@freenet.de>, relay=emig.freenet.de[195.4.92.217]:25, delay=0.62, delays=0.03/0.01/0.56/0.03, dsn=4.0.0, status=undeliverable (host emig.freenet.de[195.4.92.217] said: 457 Greylisted, please come back later. (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Jul 22 19:48:42 host postgrey[2762]: action=greylist, reason=new, client_name=mout1.freenet.de, client_address=2001:748:100:40::2:3, sender=someone@freenet.de, recipient=someone@myserver.de
Jul 22 19:48:42 host postgrey[2762]: action=greylist, reason=new, client_name=mout1.freenet.de, client_address=2001:748:100:40::2:3, sender=someone@freenet.de, recipient=someone@myserver.de
Jul 22 19:48:42 host postfix/smtpd[22813]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mout1.freenet.de[2001:748:100:40::2:3]: 450 4.1.7 <someone@freenet.de>: Sender address rejected: unverified address: host emig.freenet.de[195.4.92.217] said: 457 Greylisted, please come back later. (in reply to RCPT TO command); from=<someone@freenet.de> to=<someone@myserver.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<mout1.freenet.de>
Jul 22 19:48:42 host postfix/smtpd[22813]: disconnect from mout1.freenet.de[2001:748:100:40::2:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The message shown in the log provided was greylisted, meaning that the sending mail server (mout3.freenet.de) must attempt to resend the message for it to get through. After the first proper retry, the sending server should be added to the exception list automatically so any subsequent mails sent from that server would not be greylisted.

You can add the server to the whitelist manually to solve the issue:

> In postgrey its possible to whitelist senders as well as recipients.
>   All that needs doing in order to whitelist a host is to add its fully
>   qualified domain name or its ip address to the
>   /etc/postfix/postgrey_whitelist_clients.local file. eg:
>
> ```
> 192.168.1.10
> mydesktop.office.mydomain.com
> ```
>
> Now all email recieved from either 192.168.1.10 or mydesktop.office.mydomain.com will not be
>   greylisted, it will be accepted immediately ( as long as its valid,
>   and passes all postfix rules ). On the other hand if you want to
>   whitelist a recipient you can add their username part of the email
>   address to the /etc/postfix/postgrey_whitelist_recipients file. eg:
>
> ```
> postmaster@ 
> abuse@ 
> theboss@
> ```
>
> Now all emails being received for any of
>   these email address' wont be greylisted, and all email will be
>   accepted right away.

[Greylisting HOWTO](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postgrey#head-78d9f739ec1f00c2e2a2d3e11fabc2b2f4bb5ce6)

Comment: the server try resending for 2h. the timer of postgrey is set to 300s.

Comment: @FrankStein Please update your question with the contents of your postgrey_whitelist_clients.local file, and the parts of the mail.log file showing both the initial attempt as well as the retry.

Comment: i think you can see that the whitelist is okay. the log says "action=pass, reason=client whitelist" but do not use it. But i will update.